# Extjs Grid - fit height based on content?

Tags: extjs

How can I set the height of a grid to fit it's content?

See this fiddle here, the first grid has a `height: 200`, that is ok. The second has no height and I would like to make the height to fit the grid content. Grid Header and Column headers are displayed, but the grid rows not.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/385b

Answer (score 1):

[image]
You can use layout: 'vbox' and flex: 1 in the second grid. Something like this:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
            data: [{
                'name': 'Lisa',
                "email": "lisa@simpsons.com",
                "phone": "555-111-1224"
            }, {
                'name': 'Bart',
                "email": "bart@simpsons.com",
                "phone": "555-222-1234"
            }, {
                'name': 'Homer',
                "email": "home@simpsons.com",
                "phone": "555-222-1244"
            }, {
                'name': 'Marge',
                "email": "marge@simpsons.com",
                "phone": "555-222-1254"
            }]
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
            fullscreen: true,
            layout: 'vbox',
            defaults: {
                style: 'border: 1px solid grey;' // To see the borders
            },
            items: [{
                title: 'Simpsons - height: 200',
                xtype: 'grid',
                height: 200,
                store: store,
                columns: [{
                    text: 'Name',
                    dataIndex: 'name',
                    width: 200
                }, {
                    text: 'Email',
                    dataIndex: 'email',
                    width: 250
                }, {
                    text: 'Phone',
                    dataIndex: 'phone',
                    width: 120
                }],
            }, {
                title: 'Simpsons - autofit?',
                xtype: 'grid',
                flex: 1,
                store: store,
                columns: [{
                    text: 'Name',
                    dataIndex: 'name',
                    width: 200
                }, {
                    text: 'Email',
                    dataIndex: 'email',
                    width: 250
                }, {
                    text: 'Phone',
                    dataIndex: 'phone',
                    width: 120
                }],
            }, {
                xtype: 'container',
                html: "Some other content"
            }]
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, indeed this "kind of" solves it. I was wondering if there is a possibility to avoid using flex and just display the "Some other content" right after the grid.

Comment: You can use bottom toolbar(dockedItems) in the second grid and put there some text.. or you can use only two components, the first one is the grid with height and the second one is container with grid and some-other-content.. there are different layouts you can use.

Comment: I've posted the solution I got from the support team of sencha. It look good.

Comment: 'inifinite: false' have hidden the content of the grid. 'maxHeight: 700' is ok, but in case of >100 rows in the second grid, you will need vertical scrolling to see the "Some other content".

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to specify one of these 2:

- `maxHeight` property for the grid

OR

- set `infinite` to false.

```
    //maxHeight: 800,
    infinite: false,
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/386n